# Выделить домен сайта с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Отрывок текста:

```html
<a href="http://credit.rbc.ru/news/other/2009/03/30/70781.shtml">ЦБ РФ отозвал лицензии еще у двух банков</a></li><li><a href="http://credit.rbc.ru/recommendation/auto/2009/03/26/70657.shtml"', '"'), ('<a href="http://www.rbc.ru/services/"', '"'), ('<a href="http://graph.rbc.ru/"', '"'), ('<a href="http://portfolio.rbc.ru/"', '"'), ('<a href="http://export.rbc.ru/"', '"'),
```

Задача выделить все домены такого вида: `credit.rbc.ru` (любой сайт может быть). Я написал регулярное выражение, которое ищет все, начиная с `<a href=`(так требуется по условию). Моя задача теперь извлечь сам домен. Как выделить нужную группу, я не могу понять (т.е. текст после http://). Вот мой вариант: `re.findall(r'<a href="https?://\w[\d\w\.-]+', res.text)`.Тестирую [на этом примере](https://regexr.com/6ll93). Задание учебное, поэтому не использую beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

Случайно нашел ответ на свой вопрос, взяв выражение в скобки после `https?://`. Хотя этот вариант не работал на сайте https://regexr.com/, но заработал на python. Получилось так: `re.findall(r'<a.+?href="https?://(\w[\d\w\.-]+)', res.text)`